# Infinite series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(\frac{1}{2})^{n-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

I am a little confused about calculating $\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(\frac{1}{2})^{n-2}$. I know that the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n}$ yields $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$. However, now I start at $2$ and the exponents start at $n-2$ I am a little confused. Any help?

Comment: your series is equal to $ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}nz^{n-2}= \frac{1}{z^{2}}( \frac{1}{(1-z)^{2}}-z) $

Answer (score 1):

You can solve $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n =a_1 +  \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n $$ for the sum on the right, and you know how to compute the sum on the left.

You can also pull out a numeric factor, like $\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{-2}$, from a sum.

Answer (score 0):

Following your approach,
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-2}=4\sum_{n=2}^\infty n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}=4\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}\right)=4\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1/2}{(1-1/2)^2}\right)=6.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: prove by induction that for the finite sum holds
$$\sum_{n=2}^k\frac{n}{2^{n-2}}=2^{1-k} \left(-2 k+3\ 2^k-4\right)$$